# Use dynamic selector with Puppeteer to click different divs in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer to automate an application. There is a feed with multiple divs in it. I am able to select the correct div inside a loop with the following "querySelector" by incrementing a counter.

```
let form = document.documentElement.querySelectorAll("div[role=feed]").item(0).childNodes[current + 1].querySelector("form")
```

With Puppeteer I would like to click the div. How can I click the selector above with Puppeteer? Like:

```
await page.click(selector)
```

Comment: Your first code chunk is browser code while the second is Node/Puppeteer. If you want to issue a native DOM click, just add `.click()` to the end of your top code inside the `evaluate` callback I assume it's in. If you want to use a trusted Puppeteer click, return the node from a `evaluateHandle` block or `page.$` and then use `ElementHandle.click()`. If neither of these work, please add details, context, share the actual page and a [mcve] so I can write a specific answer without guesswork as to your use case. Thanks.

Comment: `With Puppeteer I would like to click the div. How can I click the selector above with Puppeteer?` Do you want to click this div `div[role=feed]` or you need to click the `form` element?

Comment: There are multiple forms inside the feed and I would like to iterate through them all. Dont know why but `querySelectorAll(...).click()` does not work. Via Puppeteer it does but I dont know how to iterate